# Tensorflow XLA "Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter."

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I am trying to run my Tensorflow program with [JIT compilation, using XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/jit). I want to understand the compiled computation graph that it produces. However, when it fails to run, with:

```
env "TF_XLA_FLAGS=--xla_generate_hlo_graph=.*" python Genetic\ Algorithm\ in\ Tensorflow-Part\ 2.py
2017-06-10 16:22:45.577462: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 8 visible devices
2017-06-10 16:22:45.578014: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:183] XLA service 0x7fb80bb1e800 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2017-06-10 16:22:45.578038: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:191]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2017-06-10 16:22:45.608555: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_graph_dumper.cc:454] computation cluster_28[_XlaCompiledKernel=true,_XlaNumConstantArgs=0,_XlaNumResourceArgs=0].v5 [CPU: pipeline start, before convolution-canonicalization]: /tmp/hlo_graph_0.9QsDAz.dot
2017-06-10 16:22:45.608686: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_graph_dumper.cc:454] computation cluster_31[_XlaCompiledKernel=true,_XlaNumConstantArgs=0,_XlaNumResourceArgs=0].v5 [CPU: pipeline start, before convolution-canonicalization]: /tmp/hlo_graph_1.wVNyt7.dot
2017-06-10 16:22:45.608872: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_graph_dumper.cc:454] computation cluster_28[_XlaCompiledKernel=true,_XlaNumConstantArgs=0,_XlaNumResourceArgs=0].v5 [CPU: after convolution-canonicalization, before simplification]: /tmp/hlo_graph_2.4hrkR3.dot
2017-06-10 16:22:45.609154: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_graph_dumper.cc:454] computation cluster_31[_XlaCompiledKernel=true,_XlaNumConstantArgs=0,_XlaNumResourceArgs=0].v5 [CPU: after convolution-canonicalization, before simplification]: /tmp/hlo_graph_3.HeUKAJ.dot
2017-06-10 16:22:45.609179: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_graph_dumper.cc:454] computation cluster_28[_XlaCompiledKernel=true,_XlaNumConstantArgs=0,_XlaNumResourceArgs=0].v5 [simplification: pipeline start, before algsimp]: /tmp/hlo_graph_4.VI87aX.dot

...

2017-06-10 16:23:40.250376: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/hlo_graph_dumper.cc:454] computation cluster_19[_XlaCompiledKernel=true,_XlaNumConstantArgs=0,_XlaNumResourceArgs=0].v9 [CPU: after dce, pipeline end]: /tmp/hlo_graph_33151.ks3lim.dot
2017-06-10 16:23:40.291384: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.291447: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.292857: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.293537: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.293568: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.294546: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.295143: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.296903: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.298365: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.302371: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.302445: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.302472: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.302507: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.302531: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.302559: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.303833: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.304199: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.304269: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.304402: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.304489: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.305516: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.305792: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.305846: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.306228: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.316243: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.316306: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.316378: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.316422: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n23 input 1: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.316850: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
2017-06-10 16:23:40.317028: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Invalid argument: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Genetic Algorithm in Tensorflow-Part 2.py", line 280, in <module>
    sess.run(run_ga())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Error evaluating n24 input 2: Operand to ComputeConstant depends on parameter.
     [[Node: n24 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, _XlaCompile=true, _XlaScope="jit_scope_0", _XlaSeparateCompiledGradients=false, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=0](n22, n5, n15, n4)]]
    Conversion from TensorFlow graph to XLA computation failed.
     [[Node: cluster_3/_2/_3 = _XlaLaunch[Nresources=0, Targs=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], Tconstants=[DT_INT64, DT_INT32], Tresults=[DT_INT32], function=cluster_3[_XlaCompiledKernel=true, _XlaNumConstantArgs=2, _XlaNumResourceArgs=0], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](while/map/while/cond/multinomial/Multinomial, cluster_16/_20/_21:2, cluster_16/_20/_21, while/map/while/cond/strided_slice_2/Switch:1, ^cluster_16/_20/_21)]]
```

In the docs it says that "If an operator cannot be compiled, TensorFlow will silently fall back to the normal implementation." So why is this run failing? When can XLA compilation not be used?

For reference, I am on OS X and compiled Tensorflow r1.1 from source with XLA enabled.

The file I am trying to compile is [available here](https://github.com/saulshanabrook/graph-computation-play/blob/6a715797a609dabc261bbd3bd7616be09f9970e5/Genetic%20Algorithm%20in%20Tensorflow-Part%202.py).